# Formula to match data with multiple options and extract highest value each time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Having trouble with some data I am trying to organise for a personal project.

My reference master data is 10 digits long and my incoming data is only partially complete at 8 digits long, however the 8 digits are the same as the first 8 digits as the 10 digit data set.

A number of the 8 digit values could have more than one match in the 10 digit data set but my aim is to match it to the highest value and extract this next to my 8 digit values

Is there a formula possible for this or what would be the best way to go about this?

This is an example of how my data should look, is it possible ?

```
Master 10   8 digit incomplete  extracted max value

6403999810  64039998    Nil

6403999890  64039998    6403999890

6404110000  64041100    6404110000

6404191000  64041910    6404191000

6404199000  64041990    6404199000
```

Comment: Can you explain why first one is `Nil`?

Comment: the nil is there to signify that the value found was not the greatest possible value available. e.g  6403999890 is greater than 6403999810 so nil was returned instead of 6403999810

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this **Array Formula  CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=MAX(IF(TEXT(B1,"@")=LEFT(IF($A$1:$A$9<>"",$A$1:$A$9),8),$A$1:$A$9))
```

Put into `D1` and pull down.

You can insert other conditions in the first part fo the `IF`-function with `AND`.

[image]